# about bootstrap form-inline's input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
            <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label no-padding-right">A :</label>
            <input type="text" name="a1" class="form-control" id="a1">
            ～
            <input type="text" name="a2" class="form-control" id="a2">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label no-padding-right">B :</label>
            <input type="text" name="b1" class="form-control" id="b1">
            ～
            <input type="text" name="b2" class="form-control" id="b2">
            </div>
```

I would like to have input boxes as:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you really need to get done :

```
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <label for="a1" class=" control-label no-padding-right">A :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="a1" class="form-control" id="a1">
                    ～
                    <input type="text" name="a2" class="form-control" id="a2">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="b1" class="control-label no-padding-right">B :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="b1" class="form-control" id="b1">
                    ～
                    <input type="text" name="b2" class="form-control" id="b2">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jo69e0op/

Comment: thank you very much!
but my source link some css, give rise to other question. I don't know how to upgrade all css in stackoverflow.com or jsfiddle.net !

Comment: my data's URL: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxo1jNlnV4JMb1duUFljSU8wR2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to get it as in the red box. right? Should it stay like that on all screens or just PC?

Comment: Red & gray, you've been a big help, thanks for your kindness!

Comment: So what I answered is the correct one. right? Then give it a Tick :)
You're welcome

Comment: If the second input jumps down in the gray view, Just remove the class "form-control" from <input>. it will get like in the gray box on small screens.

Comment: gray box have 4 input, remove all's "form-control"?

Comment: I try to remove 4 input's "form-control", haven't changed a bit. and how to give a "Tick" for you? I'm new user in the site.